# Ubuntu 18.04 - Unable download Tomcat 7 or 9 from 'wget' command?

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, curl, wget

In ubuntu 18.04, I am trying to install Tomcat 7 but not able to download the folder via `wget` command. Referred from https://tecadmin.net/install-tomcat-7-on-ubuntu/

Also try to install Tomcat 9 from [https://tecadmin.net/install-tomcat-9-on-ubuntu/#:~:text=Tomcat%20is%20a%20web%20server,18.04%20LTS%20%26%2016.04%20LTS%20systems](https://tecadmin.net/install-tomcat-9-on-ubuntu/#:%7E:text=Tomcat%20is%20a%20web%20server,18.04%20LTS%20%26%2016.04%20LTS%20systems) because of the above issue but getting same error as,

```
$ wget http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.27/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.27.tar.gz
--2020-12-11 14:52:19--  http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.27/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.27.tar.gz
Resolving www-eu.apache.org (www-eu.apache.org)... 2a01:4f9:2a:185f::2, 95.216.24.32
Connecting to www-eu.apache.org (www-eu.apache.org)|2a01:4f9:2a:185f::2|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://downloads.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.27/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.27.tar.gz [following]
--2020-12-11 14:52:20--  https://downloads.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.27/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.27.tar.gz
Resolving downloads.apache.org (downloads.apache.org)... 2a01:4f8:10a:201a::2, 88.99.95.219
Connecting to downloads.apache.org (downloads.apache.org)|2a01:4f8:10a:201a::2|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2020-12-11 14:52:22 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

I referred https://noviello.it/come-installare-apache-tomcat-9-su-ubuntu-18-04-lts/ too but no use of it.

How can I install Tomcat and which version suits to my ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 0):

Always try and download from the proper developer resources:

https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi